How to obtain PPPOE password from ZTE F670LV9.0 router?
I backed up the configuration file from the 192.168.1.1 page into a USB and tried opening the usbbak.cfg in routerpassview, but didn't recieve anything, so I opened it in a text editor and it seems to be obfuscated. If the file is encrypted, how do I break the encryption and get the PPPOE password?
